# What is the difference between a kill and assist in ME3 multiplayer

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-3-multiplayer

During my multiplayer games I've been getting ether an 'assist' or a 'kill' when a target I was hurting died, and a number next to it. I'm guessing that the numbers represent the amount of xp I got for that kill. What I don't understand is when a kill is a 'kill' and when just an 'assist'. It happened to me that I've got a kill on the same enemy type that I got an assist for, but with less xp. How is a kill/assist determined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Kill**:  You were the one who scored the final hit on the enemy to put them down.

**Assist**: You damaged the enemy but didn't land the last hit which killed him.

It is completely possible for a person who assisted in killing an enemy to get more points than the person who eventually kills that enemy.  It all depends on how much each person personally contributed to the enemy's eventual demise.

Comment: It's also possible to get 0 points from an assist (it actually comes up with, `assist: 0`), if, for instance, you deal little enough relative damage (mostly applies when teammates use rockets).

Comment: @RavenDreamer interesting, I wonder if it tracks ALL damage done including overkill, or just the actual reduction in health before the target dies

Comment: @BenBrocka I think that it counts overkill. I also assume that it's just not storing damage as Ints, which means it's some non-zero number that simple gets rounded down to zero for display.

Comment: its also possible to squeeze more points out of a target than possible (I believe).  If you do a massive killing blow on an almost dead target(such as cloaked with m-98 widow) you'll get a lot of points for the kill (400+).  The assister can still get 200-300 for doing the health damage for a total of 600+ points on a target normally worth ~450